# Generating plain-text report in OpenSCAP

Tags: openscap

I have set up OpenSCAP for compliance testing. Right now I am generating xml and html reports.

oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_custom --results-arf results.xml --report report.html ssg-centos7-custom.xml

I really need to generate text reports. The documentation says:

> 3.3. Generating Reports and Guides
> Another useful features of oscap is the ability to generate SCAP content in a human-
> readable format. It allows you to transform an XML file into HTML or plain-text
> format.

But then only gives examples of generating html reports. Does anybody know how to generate a text report?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this information in the user's manual is wrong. We can't generate a plain text report. We can do only XML results (ARF) or HTML report, or extract the remediation scripts (oscap xccdf generate fix).

But actually it's a nice idea to be able to generate a plain text and I think it could be useful for multiple users. If you're a Red Hat customer, you can open a ticket with Red Hat to request the feature.

Comment: Thanks Jan! That explains why I couldn't figure it out. I'll see about opening a feature request.